# Bluetooth trackball and screen mirroring

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've very interested in a new project, but it requires the user be able to access the phone's display via a wireless trackpad and screen.  I'm thinking bluetooth is the best way to go.  I can find a few resources regarding the bluetooth classes, but I can't find any resources for mirroring the phone's display or manipulating the ui with a trackball using blue tooth.

Are these two things possible?  Could someone give me some information or point me towards some resources?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to remotely control your Android Device with a Trackpad using Bluetooth for the connection? Do you need this for the whole Android System or just for your App?

If just for your App, their should be a way of doing this since communication between two Bluetooth-Devices runs over Sockets (like Client-Server communication). See the [Androids Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html). But I'm also not sure how you plan to make the Android Device understand the Bluetooth-Commands which the Trackpad is sending to it (if you can even get both of them to connect to each other).

If you need it for the whole System, I'm not sure if this is possible (without rooting the phone and maybe writing some drivers for it), as I don't know any way of emulating a touch/click on the screen (which is basically what you want).

Although I know that there are some experiments running to connect a Bluetooth-Keyboard with an Android Device. But their is nothing official yet and nothing to look into (like SourceCode) as far as I can tell.

But maybe I'm looking at this a lot too complicated...

Comment: Android can already handle trackballs. Most new phones tend to not have them, but a lot of original Android phones do.  I was hoping I could leverage this, but do it over bluetooth.  Ideally, I want to control the whole system with the trackball and mirror the device's screen onto the second screen.

Comment: Sure they can handle trackballs, that wasn't my point. My point is, that you'll need to emulate the Trackball (like if you wanted to control your PC remotely, you would need to emulate a mouse movement/click to make the System actually respond on it).